# Disable <track> subtitles default background

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, safari, video-subtitles

I have a video with subtitles on my project, which I've included using the standard `<video>` tag and subs through the `<track>` tag. By default, the subs have a black background in Chrome, Safari and Firefox (as shown in the picture below) and I'm not being able to get rid of it.

[Screenshot of mentioned subs' black background in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOehx.png)

Tried applying the following but it didn't work:

```
video::cue {
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

It seems that this background is actually not styled through the `background-color` property - does anyone know how I can access it in order to hide it or make it transparent?

Thanks in advance!